# Modifying Freemarker Dates

Tags: datetime, freemarker

I'm attempting to use freemarker to add 20 days to an existing date (now). Below is example:

```
${(.now?long + 20 * 86400000)?number_to_date?string("YYYY-MM-DD")}
```

The output of the above (run on 01-24-2020) is "2020-02-44". I am correctly populating the month, but my days are being populated current day + 20, not properly rolling over to generate a valid date.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The date built-in `?string` takes a [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) pattern. There `D` is day in the year. You need to use `d` for day in the month.

Comment: @MrMark good to hear. If it helped you, please accept the answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers